# Android Jetpack Compose (Composable) Change Image source with animation

Tags: android, android-animation, android-jetpack-compose

I have a vector drawable set as source via the painter attribute to an Image. Now I want to change the source, but also animate the change. By animation I don`t mean morphing animation with the path data, rather I want to have simple FadeIn, FadeOut effects. So once the source is changed I want the to hide the previous and show the current drawable with fade animation.

[image]

Now I am doing a workaround, I am using 2 Images with the sources of the two different images, and using [AnimatedVisibility](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation#high-level-apis) to change the visibility of the images, to match the theme. Is there a standard way of changing the source with animation?

Here is the hack I use, which is very ugly in my opinion

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalAnimationApi::class)
@Composable
fun AnimatedImage(modifier: Modifier, isLightTheme: Boolean, srcLight: Int = R.drawable.ic_sun, srcDark: Int = R.drawable.ic_moon) {

    val colors = LocalColors.current
    val (enter, exit) = remember {
        arrayListOf(
            fadeIn(animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 1500)),
            fadeOut(animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 500))
        )
    }

    AnimatedVisibility(
        visible = !isLightTheme,
        enter = enter as EnterTransition,
        exit = exit as ExitTransition
    ) {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = srcDark), contentDescription = "",
            colorFilter = ColorFilter.tint(colors.secondsArrow),
            modifier = modifier
        )
    }

    AnimatedVisibility(
        visible = isLightTheme,
        enter = enter,
        exit = exit
    ) {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = srcLight), contentDescription = "",
            colorFilter = ColorFilter.tint(colors.secondsArrow),
            modifier = modifier
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use basic `Crossfade` animation:

```
Crossfade(
    flag,
    animationSpec = tween(1000)
) { targetState ->
    Image(
        painterResource(if (targetState) R.drawable.ic_redo else R.drawable.ic_undo),
        contentDescription = null,
        modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Black)
    )
}
```

Or if you need a more complex one, you can use `AnimatedContent` - my example is equivalent to your double-`AnimatedVisibility`:

```
AnimatedContent(
    flag,
    transitionSpec = {
        fadeIn(animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 1500)) with
                fadeOut(animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 500))
    }
) { targetState ->
    Image(
        painterResource(if (targetState) R.drawable.ic_redo else R.drawable.ic_undo),
        contentDescription = null,
        modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Black)
    )
}
```

Note that in both cases it's required to use `targetState` passed in the content lambda, because this lambda is recomposed multiple times during transition.

You can find more info in Compose Animation [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation)

Comment: Hi very nice answer but what if the painterResource value is a state, i.e. the image URL or ressource is part of the state in our viewmodel for example. How the animation knows it should start when the state in viewModel is changed ?

Comment: @Jerome animation will start if `targetState` value passed to `AnimatedContent` is changed since the last recomposition. You can store state in a view model in a variety of ways - compose mutable state, the `Flow` or `LiveData` - anything that will cause recomposition when the value changes.